# Load remote script only if cached, fallback to local

Tags: javascript, html, caching, cdn, privacy

I'm guessing this is impossible, but maybe someone has thought of something smart already:

Would it be possible to load jQuery using the version that's in the browser cache (from some major CDN, say) if it's cached, and otherwise load it from my site? This way, users would never make a request to the CDN because of reaching our site, but the site would stay fairly fast for most users.

Ideally one would do `<script src="./jquery.min.js" same-as-cached="https://thecdn/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha-…"/>`, but since AFAIK nothing like that exists, is there a way to get the script from cache without making a request?

Comment: impossible, but you can improve cache and making your page work offline if you use service workers

Comment: Just because I am curious: where is the advantage ?

Comment: There's a minor privacy disadvantage with CDN's. If a resource is uncached, which happens *in particular* with privacy conscious people who run in fresh browser profiles or similar, the CDN gets at least the IP (and list of requested resources). It's not a big thing, but it would be nice if there were a way to avoid it while keeping some of the speed advantage, in these gdpr-days. (I know there is https://www.decentraleyes.org/ but that puts the onus on users.)